# How to substitute all words following a pattern in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, regex

Given the string below:

```
"Hello this is a :sample string :hello"
```

I want to substitute `:sample` and `:hello` with something else. How can I do this in JavaScript?

This is what I tried:

```
var sentence = "Hello this is a :sample string :hello";
var words = sentence.split(" ");
for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
     if (words[i].startsWith(":")) {
       words[i] = words[i] + ":";
    }
}

sentence = words.join(" ");
console.log(sentence)
```

Comment: Use string.replace().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `String.replace()`. It can accept specific strings or regular expressions.